# Not getting the expected output in formatting the date

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-parsing

I want my program to validate that the date format is `mm/dd/yyyy`. I don't want to use any throw/catch blocks.

```
class FunWithScheduling
{
    public void AddView()
    {
        ...
        ...

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Date Scheduled For the Meeting:");
        string Date = Console.ReadLine();
        DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(Date);
        string formatted = date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
        if (Date != formatted)
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Choice");

        ...
        ...
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        FunWithScheduling a = new FunWithScheduling();
        a.AddView();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
DateTime dt;
if (
    DateTime.TryParseExact(
        "08/03/2013", 
        "MM/dd/yyyy", 
        null, 
        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, 
        out dt
    )
)
{
    //Date in correct format
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out `DateTime.TryParseExact`

Answer (score 1):

you need to change this line

```
 DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(Date);
```

To

```
DateTime date;
if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(Date,"MM-dd-yyyy",new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                          DateTimeStyles.None, 
                          out date))
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Choice");
 }
```